# how to append a buffer[] to a vector<> and then copy it to a jbytearray?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, sane

This does a sane_read (with [SANE](https://sane-project.gitlab.io/standard/)) and converts to a java application.

`expected_bytes` might not be 100% accurate, hence the use of a vector<>.

Something is wrong because the resulting image is wrong. It works if I use `env->SetByteArrayRegion` directly.

So, the error is on the vector<> context.

What am I doing wrong?

```java
    long expected_bytes = pars.bytes_per_line * pars.lines *
                            ((pars.format == SANE_FRAME_RGB
                              || pars.format == SANE_FRAME_GRAY) ? 1 : 3);

    //fprintf (stderr, "Expected bytes: %ld\n", expected_bytes);

    SANE_Byte buffer[2048];
    SANE_Int bytes_read;
    vector<SANE_Byte *> data;
    data.reserve(expected_bytes);

    do {
        status = sane_read((SANE_Handle *)hnd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytes_read);

        if (status != SANE_STATUS_GOOD) {
            if (status == SANE_STATUS_EOF) {
                break;
            }

            throwEx(env, getError(status));
            break;
        }

        if (bytes_read > 0) {
            data.insert(data.end(), &buffer, (&buffer) + bytes_read);
        }
    }
    while(1);

    jbyteArray bytes = env->NewByteArray(data.size());
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(bytes, 0, data.size(), (const jbyte *) &data[0]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you've declared `data` as a vector of `SANE_Byte*` (i.e. pointers) rather than a vector `SANE_Byte` (raw characters).  When you call `SetByteArrayRegion()`, you want to be passing in a pointer to character data, but you're actually passing in a pointer to an array of pointers; those will not yield the desired image data.

The second problem is the way you're inserting data into the vector:

```
SANE_Byte buffer[2048];
...
data.insert(data.end(), &buffer, (&buffer) + bytes_read);
```

Since `buffer` has type `SANE_Byte[2048]` (array of 2048 bytes), that means that `&buffer` has type `SANE_Byte(*)[2048]` (pointer to array of 2048 bytes).  Arrays decay into pointers to their first elements, so in most expression contexts, both `buffer` and `&buffer` have equivalent *values*, but they have very different types and don't behave the same when used with pointer arithmetic.

Suppose `buffer` is allocated at address 0x01000000.  `buffer+1` decays into 0x01000001, and `buffer+2047` decays into 0x010007FF, the last element of the array.  No surprises there.  `&buffer` is also 0x01000000, but if you consider the expression `(&buffer) + 1`, something different happens: *it points 2048 bytes past the start of the buffer*.

Here's a memory diagram:

```
Address        +0       +1     ...    +0x7FF
           +--------+--------+-   -+-----------+
0x01000000 | buf[0] | buf[1] | ... | buf[2047] |  // This row is &buffer
           +--------+--------+-   -+-----------+
0x01000800 |   ?    |   ?    | ... |   ?       |  // This row is (&buffer) + 1
           +--------+--------+-   -+-----------+
0x01001000 |   ?    |   ?    | ... |   ?       |  // This row is (&buffer) + 2
           +--------+--------+-   -+-----------+
...            ...
           +--------+--------+-   -+-----------+
0x013FF800 |   ?    |   ?    | ... |   ?       |  // This row is (&buffer) + 2047
           +--------+--------+-   -+-----------+
0x01400000 |   ?    |   ?    | ... |   ?       |  // This row is (&buffer) + 2048
           +--------+--------+-   -+-----------+
```

Thus, if `sane_read()` returns a full buffer of 2048 bytes, the memory range being inserted to the vector of `[&buffer, (&buffer) + bytes_read)` is 4 MB of character data being read out of the memory region beginning at `buffer`, which is an enormous buffer overflow.  Then, the call to `data.insert()` is interpreting those 4 MB as an array of pointers; if you're on a 64-bit system, that would be over 1 million pointers, whose contents are undefined.  To be honest, I'm very surprised this didn't crash immediately.

The proper way to construct the vector would be to declare it of type `vector<SANE_Byte>` (characters, not pointers), and copy each buffer into it on each loop iteration.  The way to reference the right byte ranges of `buffer` is not to use `&buffer` to `(&buffer) + bytes_read`, but rather `buffer` to `buffer + bytes_read`, or equivalently `&buffer[0]` to `&buffer[bytes_read]`:

```
vector<SANE_Byte> data;
...
data.insert(data.end(), buffer, buffer + bytes_read);
```

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer. it worked.